# Creating Node Linear Linked List

Tags: c, list, pointers, compiler-errors, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a linear linked list.

Seemed pretty simple but even though the code looks fine it won't compile.

Here's the header file and the main. Could you tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <malloc.h>
typedef int TYP;

typedef struct
{
    TYP info;
    node_linear_linked_list *next;
} node_linear_linked_list;

void init_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list **manager)
{
    *manager = NULL;
}

void push_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list **manager, TYP info)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *ptr =
    (node_linear_linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(node_linear_linked_list));

    ptr->info = info;
    ptr->next = *manager;
    *manager = ptr;
}

void insert_after_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list *before, TYP info)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *ptr =
    (node_linear_linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(node_linear_linked_list));

    ptr->info = info;
    ptr->next = before->next;
    before->next = ptr;
}

void pop_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list **manager)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *temp_ptr = *manager;
    *manager = temp_ptr->next;
    free(temp_ptr);
}

void delete_after_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list *before)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *temp_ptr = before;
    before->next = before->next->next;
    free(temp_ptr);
}
```

here's the main:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include "node_linear_linked_list.h"
void main(void)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *manager =
    (node_linear_linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(node_linear_linked_list));

    init_node_linear_linked_list(&manager);
    getch();
}
```

Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: `typedef struct
{
    TYP info;
    node_linear_linked_list *next;` --> `typedef struct node
{
    TYP info;
    struct node *next;`

Comment: @Maya  It is the compiler that reports errors. Read its diagnostic messages.

Comment: And don't put functions in header files, this is not how header files are used.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard

5 Tw o declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types. **Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type**.

In this declaration

```
typedef struct
{
    TYP info;
    node_linear_linked_list *next;
} node_linear_linked_list;
```

there is declared an unnamed structure. In this data member declaration

```
    node_linear_linked_list *next;
```

the name `node_linear_linked_list` is undefined.

You have to write for example

```
typedef struct node_linear_linked_list
{
    TYP info;
    struct node_linear_linked_list *next;
} node_linear_linked_list;
```

This function

```
void delete_after_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list *before)
{
    node_linear_linked_list *temp_ptr = before;
    before->next = before->next->next;
    free(temp_ptr);
}
```

has a bug. I think you mean

```
void delete_after_linear_linked_list(node_linear_linked_list *before)
{
    if ( before && before->next )
    {
        node_linear_linked_list *temp_ptr = before->next;
        before->next = before->next->next;
        free(temp_ptr);
    }
}
```

This statement in main

```
node_linear_linked_list *manager =
(node_linear_linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(node_linear_linked_list));
```

results in a memory leak because in the following statement

```
init_node_linear_linked_list(&manager);
```

the pointer is reassigned.

Also I advice to do a check in the functions whether a pointer passed as the argument is equal to `NULL`.